# Texture will not appear on the mesh

Tags: materials

For whatever reason, the texture I have (It's just an image of a color for now, but I need to be able to add more detail later) won't show up on the mesh. It's completely black in all views except solid, and in that view it just takes the diffuse color, not the texture. I'm not one to often ask the internet for questions, so I'm really at my wits end here. I have no clue why it won't take the texture!

Here's the Blend file. I'm using v2.79 Blender, with Blender Render, not Cycles Render:
https://pasteall.org/blend/86d2d787ccd64cfa8a631ae5060b2bb7

Comment: Hello and welcome. While providing a downloadable file may be valuable, it should be supplemental to info provided in the question. Please post images of the issue, your material and node setups, so we can take a look at the issue without requiring to download a file.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded your file, and though the applied material seems to have a reddish color in the material slot, the base color is light grey which is also what is appearing in the viewport views. When I changed it, the color of the model changed as well. Since the UV unwrap looks fine, I went one further and used nodes to add a checker texture just to test and it works fine. See below:

[image: Textured]

As you can see, the texturing seems fine. Is there something else i'm missing that is not working for you?

Comment: Oh lordy. I've never messed with the nodes before, I thought they were non-functional in blender render, as opposed to cycles render, or do i have that backwards?

Comment: Oh, you didn't mention you were using blender render. I'm not sure. I got these results from 2.83 using EEVEE, however, I was only doing this to test that things were in good working order, which they seem to be. I'm not sure why it's not working for you with your original setup.

Comment: Oh sorry, you're right, I should've mentioned it before. Yeah honestly I don't have the slightest clue. I really don't want to have to upd8 because i know 2.8 changes a lot about the program, but if my blender is busted then i guess i don't have much choice. Though I seriously find it hard to believe that this is blenders fault and not my own. I'm very much new to this, I've only really done model edits, as opposed to starting from scratch. So there's probably some interstitiary step I've missed thats messing everything up.

Comment: This is just my opinion (although I believe it would be heavily shared), but I really think you should think about taking the jump to 2.8. Sure, it changes a few things, yes, however, once you're used to it, it's like the difference between driving on a congested city street and an 8-lane freeway (if that makes any sense). When I first downloaded 2.8, I kept 2.79 around because it was familiar, and now I can't test your file because I deleted it soon after for being redundant and inferior. Unless you have some really special need for blender internal, I would suggest making the switch.

Comment: Yeah I guess that makes sense. Should probably do it before i fully understand 2.7 anyways. I just don't like the prospect of having to learn the ropes again :|

Comment: Just to be clear, I'd be able to open this project in blender 2.8 like you did, right? Is there anything I'll lose in the swap?

Comment: From my personal experience, the process of having to "re-learn the ropes" was relatively straightforward and smooth - especially because many tutorials are for 2.8 these days anyway, and the whole "drag" of the process was almost overcome by the wonder of how "cool and easy" everything is by comparison.

Comment: And yes, the file should open fine. You'd have to try and see though, because I don't know what your project is "supposed" to look like, 2.8 is only ~ 100Mb or so, so it's worth a try.